# Creating a strikethrough font with iText 7 (C#)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am updating a C# project to use *iText 7* and am looking to add a strikethrough effect to the value set in a form field. The code originally used an old version of *iTextSharp*, which made it fairly intuitive to create a strikethrough font:

```
// older iTextSharp code
Font strikethruFont = new Font(normalBase, 11f, Font.STRIKETHRU);
```

However I can't find any examples or documentation on how to either 1) create a font with strikethrough like above with *iText 7* and use it in a form field or 2) use some other tool (`PdfCanvas`, `Tables`, `Text` objects etc) to add a style to the form field prior to setting it's value.

```
// somehow create a strikethrough font
PdfFont strikethruFont = ???

PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);

form.GetField("Some Field Name")
    .SetValue("Some content to strike through", strikethruFont, 11f)
```

Note: I have seen examples out there using a `Text` object and then underlining it with a negative y-offset (effectively pulling the underline up into the text area, mimicking a strikethrough). Unfortunately `Text` objects can't be used with `form.SetValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to mimic a strikethrough is to draw lines onto the PDF using the `PdfCanvas` object. It's not a clean approach and I hope the iText7 people will work to improve their documentation, but I'll include my workaround here hoping it helps somebody struggling with a similar problem.

```
// set the form field value per normal
form.GetField(fieldName)
    .SetValue(fieldValue);

// draw a line exactly in the middle of the form field
Rectangle fieldFormArea = form.GetField(fieldName)
                              .GetWidgets()
                              .First()
                              .GetRectangle()
                              .ToRectangle();

float fieldWidth = fieldFormArea.GetWidth();
float fieldHeight = fieldFormArea.GetHeight();
float bottomLeftX = fieldFormArea.GetX();
float bottomLeftY = fieldFormArea.GetY();

PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(form.GetPdfDocument().GetFirstPage());

// Approach A: put a line through the whole width of the field
canvas.MoveTo(bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY + (fieldHeight / 2));
canvas.LineTo(bottomLeftX + fieldWidth, bottomLeftY + (fieldHeight / 2))
      .SetLineWidth(0.75f)
      .ClosePathStroke();

// Approach B: put a line that covers just the text in the field
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
PdfString content = new PdfString(fieldValue);
// assumes size 11 text
float textWidth = (font.GetContentWidth(content) * 11) / 1000.0f;

// then use textWidth in place of fieldWidth in Approach A above
```